# Configuration of custom paths with vue-i18n locale in Nuxt 3 with router.options.ts file

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I'm using `"nuxt": "^3.0.0"` with `"@nuxtjs/i18n-edge": "8.0.0-beta.4-27812700.b832f07"` (because of an [issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module/issues/1640)).

My problem is that I'd like to call a URL with the structure `/foo/EN/about`, which works fine, but the content from `$t('bla')` is always the default language (DE) instead of EN. There's also a console warning `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/DE/EN/about"`.

So it appears the prefix is added to my path although there is already a locale in it, which is not read. I suppose I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what the proper way would be.

I tried `strategy: prefix` and `no_prefix` in `nuxt.config.ts`, removed the `:lang` from my custom path, but then there's an error 404. It should be possible to use custom paths with a `baseURL` and a locale part that is inserted by `@nuxtjs/i18n`.

My custom routes file at `app/router.options.ts` looks like this:

```js
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema';
import About from '@/pages/about/about.vue';

export const locale = ':lang';

// https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routeroptions.html
export default <RouterConfig>{
  routes: () => [
    {
      name: 'about',
      path: `/${locale}/about`,
      component: About,
    },
  ],
};
```

This is the relevant i18n part in `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    baseURL: '/foo/',
  },
  srcDir: 'src/',
  modules: [
    [
      '@nuxtjs/i18n-edge',
      {
        defaultLocale: 'DE',
        detectBrowserLanguage: false,
        langDir: 'data/i18n/',
        locales: [
          {
            code: 'DE',
            file: 'de-DE.json',
            iso: 'de-DE',
          },
          {
            code: 'EN',
            file: 'en-GB.json',
            iso: 'en-GB'
          },
        ],
        parsePages: false,
        strategy: 'prefix',
        vueI18n: {
          legacy: false,
          locale: 'DE',
        },
        vueI18nLoader: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work on my nuxt 2 app maybe this helps.

My nuxt.config.js file looks like this:

importing i18n:

```
import i18n from './config/i18n'
```

then the module:

```
buildModules: [
      [ //i18n configuration
     'nuxt-i18n',
     {
       strategy: 'prefix',
       vueI18nLoader: true,
       //default app language
       defaultLocale: 'en',
        locales: [
         {
            code: 'en',
            name: 'English'
         },
         {
            code: 'es',
            name: 'Español'
         }
       ],
       vueI18n: i18n
     }
    ]
]
```

this is my navigation Vue file: I use `to: this.localePath('/raises')` for the to paths, I imported here a LanguageInput.Vue component to select the language.

```
<template>
  <v-app dark>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant="miniVariant"
      :clipped="clipped"
      fixed
      app
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :to="item.to"
          router
          exact
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" />
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar
      :clipped-left="clipped"
      fixed
      app
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="miniVariant = !miniVariant"
      >
        <v-icon>mdi-{{ `chevron-${miniVariant ? 'right' : 'left'}` }}</v-icon>
      </v-btn>


      <v-toolbar-title v-text="title" />
      <v-spacer />

      <LanguageInput />
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <Nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="rightDrawer"
      :right="right"
      temporary
      fixed
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item @click.native="right = !right">
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon light>
              mdi-repeat
            </v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-title>Switch drawer (click me)</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
  computed: {
    text() { return this.$t("message.hello")}
  },
  data () {
    return {
      clipped: false,
      drawer: false,
      fixed: false,
      items: [
        {
          icon: 'mdi-apps',
          title: this.$t('M-1'),
          to: this.localePath('/')
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-finance',
          title:  this.$t('M-2'),
          to: this.localePath('/raises')
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-chart-bubble',
          title: this.$t('M-3'),
          to: this.localePath('/companies')
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-file-table-box-multiple-outline',
          title: this.$t('M-4'),
          to: this.localePath('/data')
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-chart-scatter-plot',
          title: this.$t('M-5'),
          to: this.localePath('/reports')
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-tools',
          title: this.$t('M-6'),
          to: this.localePath('/builder')
        },
        {
          icon: 'mdi-human-male-board',
          title: this.$t('M-7'),
          to: this.localePath('/tours/builderpreview')
        },

      ],
      miniVariant: false,
      right: true,
      rightDrawer: false,
      title: 'Fintech Horizons'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have a component for switching the language called LanguageInput.vue :

```
    <template>
      <div class="text-center">
        <v-menu offset-y>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
            >
            <span class="mdi mdi-web"></span>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item
              v-for="(item, index) in items"
              :key="index"
              :href="item.to"
            >
              <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </v-menu>
      </div>
    </template>
<script>
export default {
data:() => ({
  items: [
  {
    icon: 'mdi-Eng',
    title: 'English',
    to: '/en'
  },
    {
      icon: 'mdi-spanish',
      title: 'Spanish',
      to: '/es'
    }
  ]
})
}
</script>
```

this setup has been working fine for me I hope it helps.